# xml parsing, warning structure name will throw an error in future

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying with simpleXML to parse an XML-Feed.

XML-Structure:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
[lastBuildDate] => 2020-08-14T11:00:00Z
[link] => https://irpages2.eqs.com/websites/swissnewsfeed/German/1/xml-feed.html?companyToken=4ed5a633-e5bc-4fc8-9284-31821a7df12c&type=all
[EquityStory-News] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [senderName] => EQS Group AG
                        [deliveryDate] => 2020-08-14
                        [deliveryTime] => 11:00:00
                        [interneId] => 2028817
                    )
                    ....
            )
         )
```

)

My PHP-Code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($FEED);
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
$ISIN = $xml->EquityStory-News[$i]->header->senderName;
print '<br>'.$ISIN;
}
```

I got the info "Warning: Use of undefined constant News - assumed 'News' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)" and nothing as content back,-(

any help what's wrong and how I can read the fixed structure without warnings.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following way to access properties with dash in between.

```
$obj->{'prop-name'}
```

So in your case.

```
$ISIN = $xml->{'EquityStory-News'}[$i]->header->senderName;
```